# How to add random noise to an array of bits in C?

Tags: c, random

I have an array of ints of predetermined size, all of values of either 1 or 0 hence representing a sequence of bits.
I want to randomly 'flip' bits in the array independently of one another with a constant probability (say, 1 in a thousand chance to flip bit i), but I need to do it in a computationally efficient way, as in not by rolling every single bit individually.
Is there a good way of doing this in C?
I thought of separately randomizing the number of errors and then choosing random indices to flip, but I'm not sure how I would randomize the number of errors to begin with..

Comment: Have you tried implementing this and verified it does not perform good enough?

Comment: so you want to be more efficient than `for (i...) bit[i] ^= (rand() < (RAND_MAX / 1000));`

Comment: Any solution that is not linear on the size of the array would be appreciated

Comment: "1 in a thousand chance to flip" and " not linear on the size of the array" are not compatible goals.

Comment: The mean number of bit flips would be the total number of bits multiplied by the probability of a single bit flip. You can vary the actual number of bit flips to perform from by adjusting the mean value by a random amount, say plus or minus 10%. Ideally, the number of bit flips should be selected randomly from the Poisson cumulative distribution, using the original mean. The `gsl_ran_poisson` function from the GNU Scientific Library could be used for that. Once you have the number of bits to flip, generate the positions of each bit flip randomly, and ideally uniquely.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a reasonably fast approach:

```
int array[10000];

for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    int index = rand() % 10000;
    array[index] = 1 - array[index]; // Flip between 1 and 0
}
```

It's not 100% equivalent to what you want but should probably be good enough. Since you want a 0.1% chance to flip a bit, just flip 1 of 1000 by randomizing the indexes. If you flip the same twice, it does not really matter.

If you want a little bit more randomness, do something like this:

```
int r = rand() % 4;
for(int i=0; i < 8+r; i++) {
    ...
```

> Any solution that is not linear on the size of the array would be appreciated

Technically, this approach is also linear. But still 1000 times faster than randomizing each individual element. However, it will be slower the more noise you want.

You could make this code more cache friendly by changing the `int` array to a `char` array. Since you're only want 1 or 0, that would work.